# Micro USB cable - Intermittent

Tags: usb, charging

I have a [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B004QOAGOQ/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004QOAGOQ) "4-port USB charger". Recently I noticed that some Android devices e.g Nexus 7 (2013), charge very slowly when one particular micro USB cable is connected but that same cable charges other devices just fine.

I am not sure what to make of this. I thought a cable functions in a binary fashion i.e. it either works or doesn't. Why would it have a degraded performance just in some situation? As long as the connection on both ends is proper so the current is flowing, that's all that matters, right?

Is there a app to check how much current/wattage is currently being received by the Android device? I tried "Battery Monitor Widget" on the Play Store and it shows the current flow as negative or 200mA, surely that can't be right when the charger is putting out 5V/1A per port. Maybe the app is buggy.

Thoughts? Thanks

Comment: More likely the app is useless without hardware support. In any case, you specifically mentioned your 4-port charger. Are you using the same port for the "good" cable and the "bad" cable? If not, there's your answer.

Comment: My Nexus 7 is running latest Android (4.4.2) and hardware specs are pretty decent but I get your point. Good point about the charger, will try using the same port for both the cables. Thanks!